# nginx proxy_pass backend server traffic

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, nginx, backend, reverse-proxy

I run the following configuration for an image-host. While everything works fine there is a lot of traffic between server 2 and 3 which I don't think there has to be. It seems server 2 is downloading data from server 3 while at the same time server 3 is also directly serving the image to the client... so why is server 2 requesting data from server 3?

50% of the total outgoing traffic on server 3 is incoming traffic on server 2.

If one requests a php file which has the following image embedded: http://example.com/upload/i/2014/12345.jpg it goes through the proxy pass, apache handles the php file and rewrites the image link which the nginx server on server 2 processes.

If one requests a php file with the the following image embedded: http://example.com/upload/i/2015/12345.jpg it goes through the proxy pass, apache handles the php file and rewrites the image link which the nginx server on server 3 processes BUT the data is being send to server 2 as well causing a massive influx of incoming traffic there. My question is why does this happen and can I somehow prevent this?

The same thing happens if I remove the apache rewrite rules and change it to nginx rewrite rules on server 1.

Server 1 (nginx)

```
server {
        server_name example.com;

        location / {
                proxy_pass                  http://1.2.3.4:21211;
                proxy_set_header            X-Real-IP  $remote_addr;
                proxy_set_header            Host "example.com";
                proxy_buffer_size           128k;
                proxy_buffers               4 256k;
                proxy_busy_buffers_size     256k;
        }
}
```

Server 2 (apache / nginx)

```
<VirtualHost *:21211>
        ServerName example.com

        DocumentRoot /storage/example.com/public

        <Directory /storage/example.com/public>
                Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        </Directory>

        <Directory "/upload">
                RewriteEngine On
                RewriteRule ^i/2014/([0-9]{5}\.jpg)$ http://fs1.example.com/2014/$1  [R]
                RewriteRule ^i/2015/([0-9]{5}\.jpg)$ http://fs2.example.com/2015/$1  [R]
        </Directory>

</VirtualHost>
```

--

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name fs1.example.com;

        access_log off;
        error_log /dev/null;

        root /storage/fs1.example.com/upload;
}
```

Server 3 (nginx)

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name fs2.example.com;

        access_log off;
        error_log /dev/null;

        root /storage/fs2.example.com/upload;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer. My software on server 2 had a PHP function (getimagesize) which was fetching images to get their dimensions. Since I split my fileservers, the function started fetching images from the remote fileserver (server 3) over the Internet causing a surge of traffic.